# How to add a load more button at the bottom of tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to add a load more button at the end of `UITableview`. It has the same feature as the load-more button in Instagram. Here is the pic.

[image: pic]

So my question is how to add it at the end of `UITableview`? Since the tableview is scrollable, I do not know how to give the button a dynamic position.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Create an empty UIView: `UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)];`
Create your button:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Load More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLoadMoreTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button sizeToFit];
```

Add you button as a subview of the view from 1.

```
[v addSubview:button];
```

Set your table's `tableFooterView` property to the view from 1.

```
self.myTableView.tableFooterView = v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every UITableView has a footerView property. Just make your custom footerView and set the property

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableFooterView
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You can add your button in the above method and set the footer to the required size in the below one

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Hope this helps.